# Upload a file to the remote server using POST

Tags: php, http-post

I want to **upload a file using as usual file uploading concept (POST method)**. But user won't upload it, I want to fetch it from localhost (a local server). In other words simply, I just want to copy a file from my localhost to server using POST (http i guess) method.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes. You can start with search - http://www.bing.com/search?q=php+http+post and pick solution you like.

Comment: I've changed title/tags to not include FTP... feel free to revert/improve my edit.